# How to process own Controller annotations in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller

In my application I have some controller classes containing actions that should have an own entry inside my navigation. I would like to mark that actions with an own annotation. To analyze that annotations I need a hook where I can add some extra functionality on registered controllers.

When starting my application I see some logs like

```
RequestMappingHandlerMapping:186 - Mapped "{[/receiptAdmin/show],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String de.diandan.web.controller.ReceiptAdminController.show(java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.Model)
```

This looks like the right direction where to add my functionality. Can anybody tell me where to add some configuration to spring config so I can do some extra-logic action-methods?

Comment: you want to annotate the fields or methods of Spring beans with your custom annotation and you want to read them at during application startup, is that what you want?

Comment: Custom annotation have nothing to do with Spring, other than Spring uses quite a few of them.  There are lots of tutorials on how to do this, but the basic process is to create a custom annotation (you will want to mark it as a runtime annotation), then use some method to find all the items that have that annotation.  The generic method for doing that is to use the Java reflections package, but in the app I work on we used Spring AOP instead.